# Why does result variable have to be declared as a pointer in the following code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int input;
    char *result;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&input);

    result= ((input % 2) ? "odd":"even");
    printf("%s", result);
}
```

Why does `result` variable have to be declared as a pointer in the code?

Comment: The strings "odd" and "even" are string literals getting stored in a read-only section of your program. The `result = ...` line assigns the address of one of those strings (depending on the evaluation of the condition) to `result`. You could just as easily use a `char` array and `strcpy` "odd" or "even" to the array and `printf` that instead, but duplicating that data, at least in this context, is a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the ternary operator.

```
((input % 2) ? "odd":"even"
```

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.15

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated). The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated), [....]

So, it produces the result either `"odd"` or `"even"` based on the evaluation. Now, to hold the result, you need to have a pointer type, as the string literals resolves to a pointer to `char`.

---

Notes:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, for *string literals*

> [..] a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.<sup>78)</sup> The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   type `char`, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence. [...]

Comment: @chux Sure I did not mean to sound wrong. that is why I added the explanation in parenthesis. Any suggestion to improve?

Answer (score 3):

So that it can point to C-style string.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
result= ((input % 2) ? "odd":"even");
```

there is used the conditional operator with string literals `"odd"` and `"even"`. String literals have types of character arrays and have static storage duration.

For example string literal `"odd"` have type `char[4]` while the string literal `"even"` have type `char[5]`.

Used in expressions with rare exception arrays are converted to pointers to their first element. Thus the string literals used in the conditional operator are converted to objects of type `char *` that contain the addresses of the first characters of the string literal.

The conditional operator returns either the pointer to the first character of the literal `"odd"` or the pointer to the first character of the literal `"even"` depending on evaluation of the condition `(input % 2)` . So to accept the result the variable `result` is declared as pointer.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.